# Has glassfish 2.1.1 a bug handling http request and handle them twice?

Tags: web-services, httpwebrequest, glassfish

I'm using glassfish 2.1.1. I've watched a mysterious http/webservice-call handling. It seams an http request is handled by two different threads.

After http basic authentication the first thread is faster. Persisting some data end, but writing response fails in glassfish internal.

The second thread fails, because it tries to persist identical data and there are (unique) constrain failures. The response (the failure) of second thread was delivered to client.

I don't won't discuss the behavior with the unique constrain failure. I've improve the webservice, so it can handle this better, because it could be happen anytime, that the client send the ws call a second time.

But I think, glassfish 2.1.1 has an bug handling http request. Is there any known issue? Have I done an mistake?

```
[#|2010-03-22T10:40:54.150+0000|INFO|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.core|_ThreadID=10;_ThreadName=main;|Starting Sun GlassFish Enterprise Server v2.1.1 ((v2.1 Patch06)(9.1_02 Patch12)) (build b31g-fcs) ...|#]
...
[#|2010-03-22T11:18:44.220+0000|FINE|sun-appserver2.1|mypackage.module.security.auth.realm.YaJdbcRealm|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-1;ClassName=mypackage.module.security.auth.realm.YaJdbcRealm;MethodName=authenticate;_RequestID=4d8f23e9-5106-4d64-b865-1638d7075bde;|JDBC authenticate successful for: 8002 groups:[roleUser]|#]

[#|2010-03-22T11:18:44.220+0000|FINE|sun-appserver2.1|mypackage.module.security.auth.login.YaJdbcLoginModule|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-1;ClassName=mypackage.module.security.auth.login.YaJdbcLoginModule;MethodName=authenticate;_RequestID=4d8f23e9-5106-4d64-b865-1638d7075bde;|JDBC login succeeded for: 8002 groups:[roleUser]|#]

[#|2010-03-22T11:18:44.220+0000|FINE|sun-appserver2.1|mypackage.module.security.auth.realm.YaJdbcRealm|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-2;ClassName=mypackage.module.security.auth.realm.YaJdbcRealm;MethodName=authenticate;_RequestID=4ca7e3e5-5ab7-41ec-b3c9-d9260b1164c9;|JDBC authenticate successful for: 8002 groups:[roleUser]|#]

[#|2010-03-22T11:18:44.220+0000|FINE|sun-appserver2.1|mypackage.module.security.auth.login.YaJdbcLoginModule|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-2;ClassName=mypackage.module.security.auth.login.YaJdbcLoginModule;MethodName=authenticate;_RequestID=4ca7e3e5-5ab7-41ec-b3c9-d9260b1164c9;|JDBC login succeeded for: 8002 groups:[roleUser]|#]

[#|2010-03-22T11:18:44.220+0000|FINE|sun-appserver2.1|mypackage.MyWebService|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-1;ClassName=mypackage.MyWebService;MethodName=enqueue;_RequestID=4d8f23e9-5106-4d64-b865-1638d7075bde;|Received WebService call to enqueue() from client 59|#]

[#|2010-03-22T11:18:44.220+0000|FINE|sun-appserver2.1|mypackage.MyWebService|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-2;ClassName=mypackage.MyWebService;MethodName=enqueue;_RequestID=4ca7e3e5-5ab7-41ec-b3c9-d9260b1164c9;|Received WebService call to enqueue() from client 59|#]
...
[#|2010-03-22T11:18:44.267+0000|FINE|sun-appserver2.1|mypackage.MyWebService|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-1;ClassName=mypackage.MyWebService;MethodName=enqueue;_RequestID=4d8f23e9-5106-4d64-b865-1638d7075bde;|Successfully finished WebService call to enqueue() from client 59|#]

[#|2010-03-22T11:18:44.329+0000|WARNING|sun-appserver2.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-1;_RequestID=4d8f23e9-5106-4d64-b865-1638d7075bde;|invocation error on ejb endpoint MyWebService at /MyWebserviceService/MyWebservice : com.sun.xml.stream.XMLStreamException2
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: com.sun.xml.stream.XMLStreamException2
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:111)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:320)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:454)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.handlePost(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:113)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.Ejb3MessageDispatcher.invoke(Ejb3MessageDispatcher.java:87)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbWebServiceServlet.dispatchToEjbEndpoint(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.webservice.EjbWebServiceServlet.service(EjbWebServiceServlet.java:157)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.AdHocContextValve.invoke(AdHocContextValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:648)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:587)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:1093)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(DefaultProcessorTask.java:666)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.executeServlet(CometEngine.java:616)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.comet.CometEngine.handle(CometEngine.java:362)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.comet.CometAsyncFilter.doFilter(CometAsyncFilter.java:84)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.async.DefaultAsyncExecutor.invokeFilters(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.async.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:164)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.async.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:92)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ssl.SSLWorkerThread.run(SSLWorkerThread.java:106)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.stream.XMLStreamException2
    at com.sun.xml.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.flush(XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:416)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:109)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: ClientAbortException:  java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:385)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:351)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:176)
    at com.sun.xml.stream.writers.UTF8OutputStreamWriter.flush(UTF8OutputStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.sun.xml.stream.writers.XMLStreamWriterImpl.flush(XMLStreamWriterImpl.java:414)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureWriteOpen(SocketChannelImpl.java:126)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:324)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:91)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:66)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:172)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.async.AsynchronousOutputBuffer.flushChannel(AsynchronousOutputBuffer.java:81)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:205)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.async.AsynchronousOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(AsynchronousOutputBuffer.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flush(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:183)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.async.AsynchronousOutputBuffer.flush(AsynchronousOutputBuffer.java:104)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.DefaultProcessorTask.action(DefaultProcessorTask.java:1100)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:237)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:381)
    ... 41 more
|#]

[#|2010-03-22T11:18:44.376+0000|WARNING|sun-appserver2.1|oracle.toplink.essentials.session.file:/mygf-211/domains/mydomain/applications/j2ee-apps/myear/myjar-myPu|_ThreadID=39;_ThreadName=httpSSLWorkerThread-8080-2;_RequestID=4ca7e3e5-5ab7-41ec-b3c9-d9260b1164c9;|
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [TOPLINK-4002] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.1 (Build b31g-fcs (10/19/2009))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Eine Zeile mit doppeltem Schlüssel kann in das 'dbo.MY_TABLE'-Objekt mit dem eindeutigen 'MY_INDEX'-Index nicht eingefügt werden.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick search at https://glassfish.dev.java.net/issues/query.cgi and did not see a report that looked like a duplicate of the situation that you are encountering here... though I may have missed it.

You should probably report this issue to the GlassFish developers, via their issue tracker: https://glassfish.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectIssues.

You may have misread the log or done something wrong in your code, but this is really hard to tell given the limited amount of info that you have given in this question...  But, SO doesn't really work as an issue analysis/resolution system.  The GF issue tracker is a better choice for that.

Comment: THanks a lot. I created an Issue: https://glassfish.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=11720