# glassfish handle request twice

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, glassfish

I'm facing with problem of duplicate handling of http request in the glassfish.
I'm using Spring 3.0 and GlassFish 4.0. My application is simplest hello world application.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Spring3MVC</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>testservlet1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>testservlet1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

testservlet1-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="springtestmvc.test1" />

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

TestBean1.java:

```
package springtestmvc.test1;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class TestBean1
{
@RequestMapping("*.html")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() 
{
    if(this.called)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Second call " + this);
    }
    this.called = true;
    System.out.println("Call " + this);
            String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
            return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

Debug:

```
INFO: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (build 89)
INFO: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
INFO: SEC1115: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
INFO: SEC1115: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
INFO: SEC1115: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
INFO: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 14ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8,080]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8,181]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4,848]
INFO: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
INFO: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3,700]
INFO: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.web.glue, null) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.web.glue [17]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.web.javax.servlet.jsp, null) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.web.javax.servlet.jsp [198]], State = [READY]
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
INFO: SEC1010: Entering Security Startup Service
INFO: SEC1143: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
INFO: SEC1011: Security Service(s) Started Successfully
INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
INFO: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
INFO: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
INFO: Created virtual server server
INFO: Created virtual server __asadmin
INFO: Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
INFO: Virtual server server loaded default web module 
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'testservlet1'
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'testservlet1': initialization started
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'testservlet1-servlet': startup date [Fri Jul 19 16:18:23 EEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/testservlet1-servlet.xml]
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@435e0f64: defining beans [testBean1,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,viewResolver]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO: Mapped URL path [/*.html] onto handler 'testBean1'
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'testservlet1': initialization completed in 959 ms
INFO: Loading application [springtestmvc] at [/springtestmvc]
INFO: Loading application springtestmvc done in 2,933 ms
INFO: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.0  (89) startup time : Felix (2,005ms), startup services(3,602ms), total(5,607ms)
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...
INFO: JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://zuzkind-System-Product-Name:8686/jndi/rmi://zuzkind-System-Product-Name:8686/jmxrmi
INFO: Grizzly Framework 2.3.1 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7,676]
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.0 2013-05-03 14:50:15...
INFO: Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain.
INFO: Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@47caf176 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@348c178c.
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common [255]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.hk2.hk2, 2.1.92) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2 [258]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-plugin-service, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-plugin-service [176]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.deployment.deployment-client, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.deployment.deployment-client [116]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-api, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-api [65]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-impl, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-impl [220]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(javax.servlet-api, 3.1.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [javax.servlet-api [94]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(javax.servlet.jsp-api, 2.3.1) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [javax.servlet.jsp-api [263]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.el.javax.el, 3.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.el.javax.el [161]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.jsftemplating, 2.1.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.jsftemplating [14]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.dataprovider, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.dataprovider [148]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.pkg.client, 1.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.pkg.client [75]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jca-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jca-plugin [257]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-corba-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-corba-plugin [241]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-web-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-web-plugin [269]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-community-branding-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-community-branding-plugin [251]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jts-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jts-plugin [6]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-plugin [62]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common-full-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common-full-plugin [275]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common [255]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-concurrent-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-concurrent-plugin [156]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin [144]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-cluster-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-cluster-plugin [192]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-lite-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-lite-plugin [230]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-updatecenter-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-updatecenter-plugin [248]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jdbc-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jdbc-plugin [48]], State = [READY]
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: visiting unvisited references
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common [255]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.hk2.hk2, 2.1.92) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.hk2.hk2 [258]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-plugin-service, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-plugin-service [176]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.deployment.deployment-client, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.deployment.deployment-client [116]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-api, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-api [65]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-impl, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.registration.registration-impl [220]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(javax.servlet-api, 3.1.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [javax.servlet-api [94]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(javax.servlet.jsp-api, 2.3.1) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [javax.servlet.jsp-api [263]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.el.javax.el, 3.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.el.javax.el [161]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.jsftemplating, 2.1.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.jsftemplating [14]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.dataprovider, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.dataprovider [148]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(com.sun.pkg.client, 1.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [com.sun.pkg.client [75]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jca-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jca-plugin [257]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-corba-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-corba-plugin [241]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-web-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-web-plugin [269]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-community-branding-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-community-branding-plugin [251]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jts-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jts-plugin [6]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-plugin [62]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common-full-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common-full-plugin [275]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-common [255]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-concurrent-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-concurrent-plugin [156]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jms-plugin [144]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-cluster-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-cluster-plugin [192]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-lite-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-ejb-lite-plugin [230]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-updatecenter-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-updatecenter-plugin [248]], State = [READY]
INFO: this.makeModuleFor(org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jdbc-plugin, 4.0.0) returned OSGiModuleImpl:: Bundle = [org.glassfish.main.admingui.console-jdbc-plugin [48]], State = [READY]
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) for context ''
INFO: Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
INFO: Loading application __admingui done in 2,255 ms
INFO: Call springtestmvc.test1.TestBean1@2b1046a9
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[testservlet1]: Servlet.service() for servlet testservlet1 threw exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: Second call springtestmvc.test1.TestBean1@2b1046a9
    at springtestmvc.test1.TestBean1.helloWorld(TestBean1.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Alike post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498785/has-glassfish-2-1-1-a-bug-handling-http-request-and-handle-them-twice). But it is old and there isn't issue. Tell me what I do wrong and how I can solve it.